# getting this error while installing cinnamon in 11.10

Tags: 11.10, apt, ssl

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 88, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 83, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (35, 'gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received.')
```

Can anyone tell me what is to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Your command opens an encrypted connection to the host. The protocol used is [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) (also known as SSL). The program [GnuTLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GnuTLS) expected a packet with special properties. Those expectations were not met and so it spelled out this error message.

Usually this is caused by some network error. When you start the program again, the error message disappears. If not, you should check your network. Maybe some device interrupts TLS packets.